# Airwatch Failed to install build on iOS 8.1.3

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, mdm, airwatch

I am trying to install build through MDM(Airwatch) but it failed to install on iOS 8.1.3, a gray colour icon with installing... appear in the device, but when i install same build on lower iOS version then 8.1.3 then it works as expected.
if any body had came across this or have any solution please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of XCode was it compiled with? Have you looked at the device logs in XCode?

Comment: I think you have same problem like me [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808558/ipad-application-could-not-upgrade-through-airwatch-mdm-on-ios-8-1-3?noredirect=1#comment45910507_28808558)